# PyFFTW uses only one core - why and how to change that?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, fftw, pyfftw

I am having difficulties using pyFFTW. I am using macOS 10.12 and installed python3, numpy and fftw using homebrew and afterfwards installed pyFFTW using pip3.

And indeed, I can use pyFFTW and the examples from the documentation, however: it always only uses one core as can be seen from the activity monitor.

I used those two examples for my tests: This one is from https://hgomersall.github.io/pyFFTW/sphinx/tutorial.html. I also upscaled the example to vectors of length 2^14 in order to see effects, sadly there are none.

```
import pyfftw
import scipy.signal
import numpy
from timeit import Timer

a = pyfftw.empty_aligned((128, 64), dtype='complex128')
b = pyfftw.empty_aligned((128, 64), dtype='complex128')

a[:] = numpy.random.randn(128, 64) + 1j*numpy.random.randn(128, 64)
b[:] = numpy.random.randn(128, 64) + 1j*numpy.random.randn(128, 64)

t = Timer(lambda: scipy.signal.fftconvolve(a, b))

print('Time with scipy.fftpack: %1.3f seconds' % t.timeit(number=100))

# Monkey patch fftpack with pyfftw.interfaces.scipy_fftpack
scipy.fftpack = pyfftw.interfaces.scipy_fftpack
scipy.signal.fftconvolve(a, b) # We cheat a bit by doing the planning first

# Turn on the cache for optimum performance
pyfftw.interfaces.cache.enable()

print('Time with monkey patched scipy_fftpack: %1.3f seconds' %
       t.timeit(number=100))
```

This one is from [PyFFTW multithreading not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534959/pyfftw-multithreading-not-working). Note that I corrected the example to use the correct modifier "threads".

```
import pyfftw
n_cpu = 4
flags = ('FFTW_MEASURE','FFTW_DESTROY_INPUT')
x_buffer = pyfftw.n_byte_align_empty((8192,8192,), 16, 'complex128')
f_buffer = pyfftw.n_byte_align_empty((8192,8192,), 16, 'complex128')
fftObj  = pyfftw.FFTW(x_buffer, f_buffer,  axes=(-2,-1), direction='FFTW_FORWARD',  flags=flags, threads=n_cpu)
fftObj()
```

I appreciate any hints how I can meaningfully debug my installation and make multithreading work.

Comment: The first case won't use more than one threads because that's the default. The second case is more interesting. Are you sure that one is not using more than one thread? I suggest doing a much smaller transform (say 1024 long 1D) and doing using `timeit`. That way you're CPU bound and not mem IO bound.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion! However, the results suggest that it is really using just one core: Adapting the second example above to perform a 1D 1024 length FFT and using timeit I obtain:

timeit(fftObj())
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.8 µs per loop

Comment: And I ran out of time using my edit...here is the rest:

Whereas using scipy.fft I obtain:
timeit(scipy.fft(x))
10000 loops, best of 3: 42.3 µs per loop

I think that this is really weird because there are no errors whatsoever. I use a 2012 13-inch MacBook Pro with an i5 2.5ghz CPU.

Comment: Compare the case with 1 thread and several threads.